# Prettier ignore for one line of code not working?? JSX -- {/* prettier-ignore */}

Tags: typescript, react-native, prettier

I am trying to use `{/* prettier-ignore */}` in front of my code block to have prettier to ignore to delete an angled bracket:

What I am trying to do is

```
ListHeaderComponent={

> (
```

Prettier keeps deleting the angled bracket and if I put `{/* prettier-ignore */}` in front of it then there is an error:

```
"message": "'...' expected.",
```

I am using typescript

```
<FlatList
        data={firstSeason.episodes.items}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <EpisodeItem episode={item} />}
        style={{ marginBottom: 250 }}
    
    ListHeaderComponent={
                <View style={{ padding: 12 }}>
        <EpisodeItem episode={firstEpisode} />
        <Text style={styles.title}>{movie.title}</Text>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
```